# How to access video file using external storage in android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private List<AssistInfo> assistInfos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String filePath1 = "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/RoveDashCam/Rove-R24K-PRO/Videos/2023_0327_174047_0005.MP4";
        String filePath2 = getFilesDir().getPath()+"/2023_0322_205825_0019.MP4";
        if(new File(filePath1).exists()){
            assistInfos = MP4Help.checkPlatform(filePath1);
            for (int i = 0; i <assistInfos.size() ; i++) {
                AssistInfo assistInfo = assistInfos.get(i);
                Log.d(TAG, assistInfo.getGps_lat()+","+assistInfo.getGps_lgt()+","+assistInfo.getSpd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code there are two File path filePath1 which i save file external directory and filePath2 i save file in internal director .

When i use file filePath1 i am unable to get file information using library even i gave file path read and write external permission but when i give permission <uses-permission **android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />** i am able to get file information using given library but MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will  rejecting our from play store because this permission .

but using filePath2 i am able to access every thing without any permission .

So can any one suggest me how to get file information from external storage .

or can any one help me how to read write file from internal storage , because we have larger file.

Or can any one help me how to read file using MEDIA store API so that i can get file information without any permission

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and in order for google play to let you through you need to ask the user for permission to access the application to external storage. Show your manifest.

Comment: @BuratinoApps Thanks for answer but <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> will reject apps paste.ofcode.org/ZnuRTjjA6WFHmdWM6dXs3r you can check this

Comment: Everything seems to be fine with your manifest. Apparently, before getting a video from external storage, you need to request permission to use external storage.

Comment: you mean manage external storage  ? but i uploaded with that permission they reject app

Comment: What is the reason for rejecting the application?

Comment: pasteboard.co/LZ2JbSqydsow.png please check this

Comment: send me the email that you received and your application.  dogbitoc@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253007/discussion-between-marsh-and-buratino-apps).

Comment: The file in the first path does not belong to your app so your app has no read access in that way. Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user select the file